# What is the meaning of event_params value for firebase conversion?

Tags: google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I am researching about firebase conversion in BigQuery and right now still not understanding at all about conversion meaning

I tried this query to check out the value of the 'firebase_conversion' key and see that all of the value is 1. 
Is this value mean that the event is marked conversion in Firebase?

```
SELECT event_name, event_params.value.int_value  FROM [firebase-public-project:analytics_153293282.events_20181003] where event_params.key = "firebase_conversion"
```

Is there anyone familiar with conversion? 
Could you guys help me to explain how firebase calculate the conversion rate? and How could we calculate it through BigQuery

Comment: Have you read firebase documentation?  https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317518?hl=en .  Regarding the SQL, I would guess the reason you are seeing all 1s is that you would want to count/sum these values.  Any sort of conversion rate would be `conversion events` divided by `pageviews/appviews/sessions/unique_users`.  You will probably need a few more items in your query.

Answer (score 1):

On top of the documentation rtenha mentioned, you can also find a specific Firebase in BigQuery section in [1]. It even has some SQL examples regarding Firebase data exploration with BigQuery.

As you say, the value of 1 in event.params.value.int_value indicates that it is marked as a conversion, and it might be useful when it comes to counting events of that type.

In order to calculate the conversion rate, you need to divide the number of USERS that have done some type of conversion among the total number of USERS.

Here is an SQL example [2] that would:

1-create a table with an only cell: the total number of users in the desired time

2-create a table with the number of users that performed each of the events marked as conversions

3-select, for each type of event, the ratio of users that performed such conversion and the total number of users

I hope this finds you well!

[1] https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9037342?hl=en&ref_topic=7029512

[2]

```
WITH t_e as (select count(DISTINCT user_id) as total_events from table_of_events 
WHERE
table_of_events.event_timestamp >
      UNIX_MICROS(TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 10 DAY))
AND table_of_events._TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20180501' AND '20180511'),

t_c as (SELECT count(DISTINCT user_id) as total_conversions from table_of_events
WHERE
table_of_events.event.params.key = “firebase_conversion”,
table_of_events.event_timestamp >
      UNIX_MICROS(TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 10 DAY))
AND table_of_events._TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20180501' AND '20180511'
GROUP BY event_name)

select event_name, t_c.total_conversions/t_e.total_events as conversion_rate

FROM t_c, t_e
```